# Remove subdomain from Google Crawler

Tags: domain, subdomain, google, web-crawler

I recently removed a sub-domain from my domain so I just have 1 website to manage.  However, if I do a google search, my old domain is still there, I removed the sub-domain well over a week ago and if you try to access the domain directly, you will get an error saying the website can not be found (the records have been deleted).

What is the easiest way to remove that sub-domain from google searches since they no longer exist?  Shouldn't google see that the domain no longer exists and delete those entries?

Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask Google to [remove your site](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=92865) from their results.

And yes, Google will eventually realize on its own that the site disappeared, but only when spidering the next time. For low-traffic sites, that may take a few weeks (only big, busy sites are re-crawled daily or weekly).

Comment: Cool - thanks, I found another page that described how to remove pages, but not sub-domains.  This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Google didn't remove the subdomain from searches yet.  It has already been almost a week.